# Differential Equations

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $X$ be a continuous field. Let $\gamma$ be a transversal section of $X$.
Then, consider
$$B(\gamma)=\{\sigma_{x_0}(t): x_0 \in \gamma \ \ and \ \ t \in (-\alpha, \alpha)\},$$
where $\sigma_{x_0}(t), \, t \in (-\alpha,\alpha),$ is a solution of $x'=X(x)$ and $x(0)=x_0$. Is it true that
$B(\gamma)$ is an open set?

Comment: Without any more regularity on $X$ than continuity, the flow is not necessarily uniquely defined.

Comment: Yes, but the set $B(\gamma)$ could be an open set?!

Comment: This question could use a more informative title.

Comment: The add is that $X(x)\neq 0$ for every $x$.